# How to find out whether a state has its own CA?

Tags: certificate-authority

Occasionally, I've seen the following:

```
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_EV_Root_CA.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G2.pem
Adding debian:Staat_der_Nederlanden_Root_CA_-_G3.pem
```

If I understand properly, the Dutch have their official CA?

How could I check for same in other countries? Or, to be more specific, Germany and US?

Answer (score 3):

The question of whether they have a CA is hard to answer, as anyone can make a CA. The important question usually is not whether they have one, but whether they have one recognized by major browsers. There is a list of CAs trusted by Mozilla [here](https://ccadb-public.secure.force.com/mozilla/IncludedCACertificateReport). You can find similar lists for other browsers and operating systems (some browsers use lists included in operating systems they run on, Chrome for example).

But for example, the US has its own CA, that is not trusted by Mozilla and other browsers/OSs. It is however trusted by Android (for some reason Android trusts way too many CAs). This means if you visit a site with certificate from this CA using Firefox, you will get an SSL error.

Comment: now why shouldn't an official state CA be trusted? What is the catch? So far the correspoding party recognizes that state's authority, of course.

Comment: @J.Doe There is no reason not to trust an official state CA just because it is official state CA. As you pointed out, `Staat der Nederlanden` is trusted. However, there is a reason US is considered enemy of the internet. You should never trust anything run by US government. More importantly, the US CA could not be bothered to fulfill the common criteria (conditions set by Mozilla, Google and others), which is a requirement to be trusted by them.

Comment: @J.Doe In PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) the word **trust** doesn't have the meaning of _"we trust this CA is run by the state A"_ but rather _"we trust this CA to issue certificates that will be accepted by the clients"_. This is crucial: in theory, nothing prevents a CA from issuing, say, a certificate for _google.com_ to someone other that Google. This certificate can then be used by a third party to impersonate Google to unsuspecting users as the browser will automatically trust such a certificate with potentially catastrophic consequences for the users' privacy and security.